# Nginx error pages outside root

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to setup nginx configuration to work like following:

My root for website would reside in path ie: /var/www/html

Is it possible to place for example error pages like 401, 404 etc inside some other path like ie: /some/other/path

I manage to get this working (to load error pages outside website root) by using this ie:

```
error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
location = /custom_404.html {
   root /path/to/my/root/for/error/pages
   internal;
}
```

Now this is problem... My 404 page could include some images and css files and when it show my 404 page the css and images are not loaded at all (it works if I put css and images for error page inside /var/www/html).

I would like to keep css and images for error pages inside same folder where error pages are... Can anyone point me how I should configure it, is it possible at all or point me somewhere since I'm searching for days about it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Say your custom_404.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Oops!</title></head>
<body>
  <h1>404</h1>
  <img src="oops.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

Change it to:

```
<html>
<head><title>Oops!</title></head>
<body>
  <h1>404</h1>
  <img src="/error/oops.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

and then in your .conf file:

```
error_page 404 /error/custom_404.html;
location /error/ {
    root /path/to/error/files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a fallback location like this:

```
location / {
    root /normal/path/to/html;
    try_files $uri @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    root /path/to/error/files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `internal` rule, which restricts the location to be accessed only from internal requests. In order to keep the `internal` Nginx rule, you can do the following things:

- Use `inline CSS`
- Convert your images to `Base64`

After doing this, you can embed the generated Base64 string into the `background-image` CSS rule as follows:

```css
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEADI.....==)
```

You can use the string with the `<img>` tags as well, just pass it to the `src` attribute as follows:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEADI.....==" />
```

Otherwise, if you still want to use external content, you will have to remove the `internal` rule from the location, dedicated to the error pages in Nginx configuration.